# Is there an alternative emulator for IOS and Xcode

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am having some trouble getting sound to play remotely through the IOS simulators. I have contacted the hosting company for the mac and they say it is a problem with IOS emulator and rdp. This is only a problem in the emulator not on the remote mac itself. I am wondering whether there are alternative emulators like genymotion for Android which maybe do not have this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many iOS features that just don't work on the simulator. The only way to test those features is on an actual device. This might be one of those situations.

Answer (score 1):

There are many iOS emulators tha can play iOS apps like iPadian OS 10.
But if you want to run iOS apps on android then apportable(google it) is your thing(if you are a developer) but if you are not a developer the there are several apps like iEMU and Cyder emulator and if you don't know how to install here is [the guide](http://emulatorforpc.com/best-ios-emulator-for-android/).

Features of iOS emulator.

1) Play iOS apps and games on android/PC
2) It needs android version 2.3 or higher
3) The size of this iOS emulator is 62 MB
4) Your primary device(on which you are planning to install this) should have         above 512 MB RAM

Comment: You misread the question. I was looking for a replacement for the xcode simulator/emulator these run the app but these are not that.